# ¿Como puedo eliminar varias imagenes basadas en un id de un registro de una tabla?

Tags: php8

quisiera que me puedan ayudar, tengo un sistema para publicar articulos con imagenes, pero al eliminar el articulo, borra unicamente una imagen y no todas las imagenes que se subieron de ese articulo.

```
    <?php

include('assets/system/core.php');

$id = $_GET['id'];

$consulta = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id2 = '$id' ");
$registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta);

$ruta = $registro['file_name'];

unlink("uploads/".$ruta);

$query = mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM amenidades WHERE id = '$id'");
$query2 = mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM images WHERE id2 = '$id'");
$query3 = mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM propiedades WHERE id = '$id'");
$query4 = mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM visit_days WHERE id = '$id'");
$query4 = mysqli_query($db,"DELETE FROM comments WHERE prpdad_id = '$id'");
header("LOCATION: ".$web_settings['weblink']."mispropiedades.php");
```

¿Como pudiera hacer para borrar todas las imagenes correspondientes a un registro de mi base de datos?

no puedo lograr hacer funcionar mi codigo

Comment: ¿Tienes en la tabla imagenes `id` (o `id1`) y `id2`? ¿En que difieren?

Comment: Tengo id que es para organizarlos, e id2 que toma es donde va el id del artículo, pero repito el problema no es ese, todo eso funciona bien, mi problema es con el unlink, que únicamente borra un archivo y no todos los archivos

Comment: Tienes que hacer fetch dentro de un ciclo: ej: `while( $registro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta) ) unlink("uploads/".$registro['file_name']);`

Answer (score -1):

Nooo, tu `DELETE` está mal. Porque lo que le dices es que elimine **UNA** imagen con `id2 = $id`

Lo que debes hacer es, obtener todos los **IDs** de las imágenes asociadas al articulo, meterlas en un array y luego hacer un delete con ese array.

```sql
$ids = [5,8,25,69];
DELETE FROM images WHERE id2 IN ('$ids');
```

Entonces vas a borrar todas las imágenes que tu array (**$ids**) tenga.

---

[Respuesta al comentario]

La lógica es la misma.

Haces un array con cada uno de los nombres del archivo y los eliminas.

Esto es Pseudocódigo

```
$rutas = ['img1','img2','img3','img4'];
foreach($rutas as $ruta){
   unlink("uploads/".$ruta);
}
```

Comment: Noo, todo esta bien, todo el codigo funciona bien, el problema es con el unlink que únicamente borra una imagen y no todas las del artículo.

Comment: Respuesta actualizada.